# Get all documents from an index using spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to my external ElasticSearch server with Spring Boot.

If I do a curl from command line, I get expected results.

```
curl "http://ipAddr:9200/indexName/TYPE/_search?pretty=true"
```

But getting this error when I try to access it via Spring Boot.

```
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Mon Sep 11 12:39:15 IST 2017</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.aggregation.impl.AggregatedPageImpl[&quot;facets&quot;])</div></body></html>
```

Not sure why a `NullPointerException` and what is `aggregartion.impl`

Here is my Spring Application:

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class PojoController {

    @Autowired
    PojoService pojoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String index() {
        return new String("Welcome:)");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody List<POJO> findAll() {
        try {
            List<POJO> pojoObj = pojoService.findAll();
            return pojoObj;
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PojoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<POJO, Integer> {

    List<POJO> findAll();

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class POJOServiceImpl implements POJOService{

    private POJORepository pojoRepository;

    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setPojoRepository(PojoRepository pojoRepository) {
        this.pojoRepository = pojoRepository;
    }

    public POJO findOne(String id) {
        return pojoRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<POJO> findAll() {
        return (List<POJO>) pojoRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

POJO class:

```
@Document(indexName = "INDEX", type = "TYPE")
public class POJO {

     @Id
     private Integer id;
     private String name;

     public POJO(){
         // empty
     }



    public POJO(Integerid, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I should be able to query all the documents in the index. Later on, I will try and use filters etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Jackson has a problem with handling your POJO (probably related to this issue: [DATAES-274](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-274)) - the problematic part is casting in repository from `Iterable` collection to `List`.

#### Update

In case of repositories, spring-data-elasticsearch behaves a bit different than you would expect. Taking your example:

```
@Repository
public interface PojoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<POJO, Integer> {
    List<POJO> findAll();
}
```

and after calling in your rest controller:

```
List<POJO> pojoObj = pojoService.findAll();
```

in debugger you will see something like this:

[image]

You would expect that `pojoObj` list contains objects of POJO class.
And here comes the surprise - `pojoObj` ArrayList contains one object of `AggregatedPageImpl` type and its `content` field is the right list that contains your POJO objects. 
This is the reason why you get:

```
Could not write JSON: ... java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.aggregation.impl.AggregatedPageImpl[\"facets\"])
```

As I wrote before, Jackson cannot handle this while serializing POJO objects.

**Solution 1**

Let repositories return `Iterable` collection (by default).

```
@Repository
public interface PojoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<POJO, Integer> {

}
```

Move the conversion part to the service but use some utility method (here with Guava) in order to have it like this:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public List<POJO> findAll() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(pojoRepository.findAll());
}
```

**Solution 2**

Use `Page` in repository (here simplified version without parameters):

```
@Repository
public interface PojoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<POJO, Integer> {
    Page<TestDto> findAll();
}
```

If you still want to operate on list - get content from page in service:

```
public List<POJO> findAll() {
    return testDtoRepository.findAll().getContent();
}
```

Comment: I changed from List to Iterable, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you also change the `findAll()` method in `POJOServiceImpl` to `Lists.newArrayList(pojoRepository.findAll())` (instead of casting to List<POJO>)?

Comment: No. Even there instead of obtaining the list, I am returning Iterable<POJO>,

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that an `Iterable` is returned from `findAll()`, I tried pagination by using `Page<POJO>`, surprisingly I don't get that error anymore.

Comment: Great! As I was in the middle of debugging the code to find the exact reason for the error - I updated my answer with the explanation in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: @Joanna I'm getting the same error but I don't appear to be using Arraylist or Page anywhere. can you check my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366848/jackson-deserialization-null-pointer?noredirect=1#comment81687459_47366848